# jQuery loading and rendering incorrectly on different PCs

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, https, jquery-easing

When I try to run my webpage on my browser/test it in other browsers, it will work perfectly with no bugs or error messages. This include IE6,7,8,9,10,newer versions of Firefox, and Chrome.

Typically, today, I decided to run it on my bosses PC and - you guessed it - it went kaput straight away. I have a simple [jQuery hover-over effect](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/) that expands a menu. This does not work on his Internet Explorer 10 or Firefox 22.0. After turning on IE Dev tools and waiting for ~30seconds the following error message is received on his PC, but not mine :

```
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
jquery.easing.1.3.js, line 39 character 1
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
SlideDownBoxMenu, line 142 character 13
```

The end of my index.html looks like this :

```
        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                /**
                * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
                * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
                * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
                * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
                * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
                */
                $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    $elem.find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'170px',
                            'height':'170px',
                            'left':'0px'
                         },400,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                        if($sub_menu.length){
                            var left = '170px';
                            if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                                left = '-170px';
                            $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                        }   
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length)
                        $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                    $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                         .andSelf().find('img')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({
                            'width':'0px',
                            'height':'0px',
                            'left':'85px'},400)
                         .andSelf()
                         .find('.sdt_wrap')
                         .stop(true)
                         .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>





    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This is the exact same as the blog listed above, except I have changed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http**s**://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

changing from http to https to that there will be no error message for "Mixed Content" on my Intranet page. Changing back to http does not solve the problem, however.

Can anyone offer me some advice on what I can look into/what might be causing this issue ?

Comment: could be a proxy server issue not allowing the browser to download anything from https - our work has something so that anything served on https in firefox won't work, try using normal http and see if that works

Comment: Consider downloading jquery and including a local copy rather than from the cdn. Alternatively, you can use a relative protocol: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` Note however, this won't work from the filesystem, you'll have to run it from a webserver.

Comment: Use the F12 Network tab or Fiddler to watch the download of the JQuery.js file; if there are any errors, post them here.